# My 'Score' Variable Is Not Printing To UI Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[SOLVED]

I have a simple block breaker game and I am in the process of designing a scoring system. I want to have the score shown live in the game in a UI Text Element, however my 'score' variable is not showing up. I have a menu that displays the game score, the bonus scores and the total score and all of those a working fine except for the game score (which is the same as the one shown live in the game). Could someone please look over my code and if possible tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

*Edit: Sorry forgot to mention, when all of the variables are printed to the console they all work perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;

    public float totalScore = 0;
    public float bonusScore = 0;
    public float score = 0;
    public float bricksDestroyed;
    public int livesRemaining = 5;
    public float totalTime;

    public int livesBonus;

    public bool isLivesBonus;
    public bool isTimeBonus;
    public bool isTotal;
    public bool isScore;

    void Update () {
        if(!Paddle.isPaused){
            totalTime += (Time.deltaTime / Time.timeScale) / 5;
        }

        score = (bricksDestroyed * (5 * Time.timeScale));
        bonusScore = (50 * livesRemaining) - totalTime;
        totalScore = score + bonusScore;

        print (score);

        livesBonus = livesRemaining * 50;

        if(isScore){
            text.text = score.ToString("F0");
        }else if(isLivesBonus){
            text.text = livesBonus.ToString("F0");
        }else if(isTimeBonus){
            text.text = totalTime.ToString("F0");
        }else if(isTotal){
            text.text = totalScore.ToString("F0");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which property stands for the one which doesn't work ?

Comment: dont put print on update

Comment: @MajkeloDev Its the score, just the score not bonus score etc.

Comment: @user2320445 Where should I print it then?

Comment: make an If statement that if the scored isChanged then print it

Comment: Did You try to debug it ? Maybe isScore is always false and it never get into it. Try to add else statement at the end and print something to see if it steped into

Comment: I edited the main post, see the Edit section, sorry, should have put that in there before

Comment: can u try text.text= 5; and see if it will work? sometimes this happens because of the length of your textbox is too small.

Comment: Tried that and it printed out 5 on the text, I also tried a much larger number and that also printed out fine onto the text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those comments but it have it solved now. Here is the completed code:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

     public Text inGameScore;
     public Text loseScore;
     public Text winScore;

     public float totalScore = 0;
     public float bonusScore = 0;
     public float score = 0;
     public float bricksDestroyed;
     public int livesRemaining = 5;
     public float totalTime;

     public int livesBonus;

     public bool isLivesBonus;
     public bool isTimeBonus;
     public bool isTotal;
     public bool isScore;

     void Update () {
         if(!Paddle.isPaused){
             totalTime += (Time.deltaTime / Time.timeScale) / 5;
         }

         score = (bricksDestroyed * (5 * Time.timeScale));
         bonusScore = (50 * livesRemaining) - totalTime;
         totalScore = score + bonusScore;

         //print (score);

         livesBonus = livesRemaining * 50;


         inGameScore.text = string.Format("{0}", 
                                   score.ToString("F0")+"\n");

         loseScore.text = string.Format("{0}" + "{1}" + 
                                         "{2}" + "{3}", 
                                         score.ToString("F0")+"\n", 
                                         totalTime.ToString("F0")+"\n",
                                         livesBonus.ToString("F0")+"\n",
                                         totalScore.ToString("F0")+"\n");
         winScore.text = string.Format("{0}" + "{1}" + 
                                         "{2}" + "{3}", 
                                         score.ToString("F0")+"\n", 
                                         totalTime.ToString("F0")+"\n",
                                         livesBonus.ToString("F0")+"\n",
                                         totalScore.ToString("F0")+"\n");
     }    
 }
```